# How can I start a ChatGPT conversation from a URL?

Tags: chatgpt

I'm wondering if it might be possible to start a new OpenAI ChatGPT conversation by using a URL. I need to find some URL like `https://chat.openai.com/chat?topic=why+is+the+sky+blue` such that when I visit the link, it starts a conversation with the question "why is the sky blue".

One use case is to add ChatGPT to Google Chrome as a "site search" search engine.

Does ChatGPT have a URL query parameter like this that I can pass to start a chat?

I am open to installing a Chrome extension, user script, etc. to open a web browser tab that shows the original ChatGPT conversation user interface.

To be clear, I specifically want to use OpenAI's ChatGPT; I’m not interested in instructions for getting this to work with competing AI chatbots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 3 March 2024, the following works with chatgpt 3.5 (assuming you already have an account and are signed in):

[https://chat.openai.com/?q=[your_prompt]](https://chat.openai.com/?q=%5Byour_prompt%5D)

Comment: This works, thanks! The UX is pretty janky: you'll be shown an empty chat window for about 4 seconds, then it "notices" your URL query and responds.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, this isn't supported natively. However, you can use the following extension:

> [ChatGPT Deeplink](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chatgpt-deeplink/bmkbpmkcppdmkdbpihmijgeilchgeapo): This adds a URL parameter to ChatGPT so you can deep link to start new conversations from other applications (like Raycast). The URL scheme is: https://chat.openai.com/?query=your+query+here
>
> It also adds a custom search engine to Chrome, so in the Omnibox you can type `ai {query}`. Triggering this command may either be a space or tab, depending on your settings (chrome://settings/searchEngines).

I didn't test it myself but I did look at the source code to make sure it didn't look malicious. You can [check out the source code online here](https://robwu.nl/crxviewer/?crx=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fchatgpt-deeplink%2Fbmkbpmkcppdmkdbpihmijgeilchgeapo), which you should do before installation.

There are other extensions that [integrate ChatGPT with search somehow](https://chromewebstore.google.com/search/ChatGPT?_category=extensions) but this seems to be the only one that does what the question asks (providing a query URL or OpenSearch in the browser).